# Crear una función que reciba por parámetro un array y compruebe si existen elementos duplicados; en caso de que existan, que los elimine con for of

Tags: javascript

Tengo ya creada la función y es funcional, pero tengo una duda y es que la manera más rápida de iterar un array es con un `for of` y quería hacer esta función con un `for of`, pero es imposible conseguirlo. Dejo la función que si funciona y el código que tengo con `for of` que no funciona.

Funcionando:

```
function removeDuplicates(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        const firtsResult = arr[i];
        
        for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++){
            const secondResult = arr[j];

            if(firtsResult === secondResult){
                arr.splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return arr
}
```

Otra manera y también funcionando:

```
function removeDuplicates3(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        
        for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++){

        if(arr[i] === arr[j]){
                arr.splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return arr
}
```

Y este el intento con `for of` pero no lo termino de conseguir, no me funciona. No sé si es posible hacerlo con `for of`:

```
function removeDuplicates2(arr){
    for (let i of arr){
        for (let j of arr){
            if (i === j){
                arr.splice(j, 1)
            }
        }
    }
    return arr
}
```

También probé a la función con `for of` a ponerle un

```
let j = i + 1
```

pero me da el mismo resultado, es decir algo así:

```
function removeDuplicates2(arr){
    for (let i of arr){
        let j = i + 1
        for (j of arr){
            if (i === j){
                arr.splice(j, 1)
            }
        }
    }
    return arr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

De poder se puede, pero este es uno de los casos que es mejor trabajar con un for con índice.

Tu problema es que el segundo `for` toma un `sub array` desde `i+1`, y tu versión del `for of` no lo hace, esto ocasiona que ambos `for of` comiencen con el mismo elemento y al comparar un elemento consigo mismo en el `if` siempre dará que son iguales.

Para obtener un `sub array` puedes usar un `slice` que requiere un índice, que como no lo tenemos tendremos que buscarlo, una manera es utilizando `indexOf`, luego tu para eliminar los duplicados utilizas un `splice` que tambien requiere un índice y volvemos a tener el mismo problema

```js
function removeDuplicates(arr) {
    for (let firtsResult of arr){
                      //  SubArray-----V         V----- Buscamos el indice y le sumamos 1
        for (let secondResult of arr.slice(arr.indexOf(firtsResult)+1)){
            if(firtsResult === secondResult){
                arr.splice(arr.indexOf(secondResult), 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return arr
}

const array = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4];
removeDuplicates(array);
console.log(array)
```

Por último, para eliminar duplicados siempre puedes utilizar un `Set`

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4];
const sin_duplicados = Array.from(new Set(array));
console.log(sin_duplicados);
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma fácil es tener un segundo array donde guardes cada elemento único y lo uses para verificar si el primer array repite sus elementos en un loop, no se si me explico bien pero te dejo el código funcionando.
Ejecutando el código podés ver como queda el resultado.

```js
let array = ["tomate", "queso", "pan", "paty", false, 0, 0, 1, true, true, 0, "pan", 1, false];

document.getElementById("array-unfiltered").innerText = array.toString();

function removeDuplicates2(arr) {
    // Copia donde guardamos NO duplicados.
    const filteredArr = [];
    
    for (const element of arr) {
        // Verificamos si la copia ya incluye el elemento del array, si NO lo tiene lo añadimos, si LO tiene ignoramos el elemento y continuamos con el loop sin sumar nada a la copia.
        if (filteredArr.includes(element)) continue;
        else filteredArr.push(element);
    }
    
    return filteredArr;
}

document.getElementById("array-filtered").innerText = removeDuplicates2(array).toString();

// Si no queres crear una copia, sobreescribí el array original.
function removeDuplicates2_noCopy(arr) {
    const filteredArr = [];
    
    for (const element of arr) {
        if (filteredArr.includes(element)) continue;
        else filteredArr.push(element);
    }
    
    // Borramos todo lo de dentro.
    arr.splice(0, arr.length);

    // Y con ... los llenamos con cada elemento del array filtrado.
    arr.push(...filteredArr);

    return arr;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset='utf-8'>
     <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
     <title>Page Title</title>
     <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
     <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
</head>
<body>
     <div>
          <h5>Array sin modificar</h5>
          <p id="array-unfiltered"></p>
     </div>

     <div>
          <h5>Array filtrado</h5>
          <p id="array-filtered"></p>
     </div>
     
     <script src='main.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```